# How to configure Play Framework 2 to make a readonly database connection?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1, bonecp

I am developing an application which would fetch data from an Oracle database. It is a reporting app, no insert, update, delete is required. I know that I can set privilege for the database user to only `select`. But can I configure the database connection in Play application to make it `readonly`? I would hate to make any change or create a new user for my app. I understand that Play Framework 2.1.3 uses BoneCp for data connectivity.

## Edit

I am using Java version of Play!

Answer (score 0):

`java.sql.Connection` has a method called `setReadOnly`, which does exactly what it says:

```
DB.withConnection{ implicit connection =>
    connection.setReadOnly(true)
    ...
}
```

An exception will be thrown when trying to execute write queries. You could also wrap `DB.withConnection` to clean things up across the application:

```
def withReadOnlyConnection[T](block: => T): T = {
    DB.withConnection{ implicit connection =>
       connection.setReadOnly(true)
       block(connection)
    }
}
```

And use it just like `DB.withConnection`:

```
def listThings: List[Stuff] = {
     withReadOnlyConnection{ implicit connection =>
         SQL(...)
    }
}
```

Of course, it would still be better to have a separate database user with the limited permissions.

---

**Edit**:

For Java it's not going to be as pretty, but the same thing applies:

```
Connection connection = DB.getConnection();
connection.setReadOnly(true);

// Do something with this connection.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I am using Java version, sorry that I forgot to mention. I have updated my question.

Comment: That doesn't really change anything. `java.sql.Connection` is the same object used for both Scala and Java, so you can do the same thing.